# iOS PromiseKit and CoreData NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext, promisekit

Having an `NSManagedObjectContext` with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` can PromiseKit be used to prettify the `performBlock:^{}` / `performBlockAndWait:^{}` ?

My first thought was to write like this :

```
- (PMKPromise *)updateModel:(Model *)model
{
    return [PMKPromise new:^(PMKPromiseFulfiller fulfill, PMKPromiseRejecter reject) {
        [_managedContenxtModel performBlock:^{
                //...
                fulfill(...)
        }];
    }];
}
```

but, I'm afraid that because the promise block will be registered in a `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` and if multiple calls to `updateModel:`, from different threads, are made it can't guarantee that the blocks from the `performBlock` are registered in the correct order.

Is there a change that this can happen ?
What about using `performBlockAndWait:^{}` instead ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dispatch_promise_on` with a concurrent queue you create yourself:

```
- (PMKPromise *)updateModel:(Model *)model
{
    return dispatch_promise_on(myQ, ^{
        [_managedContenxtModel performBlockAndWait:^{
                //...
        }];
        fulfill(...)
    }];
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, let me know and I'll try to help further.